# Oracle db Joins vs FROM a,b,c

Tags: oracle, select, join

> I've been working with SQL Server db for some time, and there I would
>   join the tables here and there and everywhere in my queries.
>
> Now I have a project with Oracle db, and as I looked through
>   procedures some oracle programmer wrote, *complex* data selection
>   query, I noticed she *never ever* used a join.

Question :

Is there anything specific about Oracle that *implies not using joins*, or its human factor ?

Comment: No, use joins wherever you need them. They are part of SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Oracle, like any other reasonable relational database, is more efficient when you do set-based operations and when you do joins rather than procedurally emulating joins (with, say, nested cursor loops).

My guess, however, is that you are not really talking about code that lacks joins.  My guess is that you are talking about code that uses a different join syntax than you are accustomed to.  Both

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM a
       JOIN b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
       JOIN c ON (b.b_id = c.b_id)
```

and

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM a,
       b,
       c
 WHERE a.a_id = b.a_id
   AND b.b_id = c.b_id
```

are queries that join `a` to `b` to `c`.  The two queries are exactly identical-- the Oracle parser will actually internally rewrite the first query into the second.  The only difference is that the first query uses the newer SQL 99 syntax to specify its joins.

Historically, Oracle was relatively late to adopt the SQL 99 syntax, there is a tremendous amount of code that was written before the SQL 99 syntax was available, and quite a few Oracle folks prefer the old style syntax out of habit if nothing else.  For all those reasons, it's relatively common to find Oracle based projects using the older join syntax exclusively.  There is nothing inherently wrong with that (though I personally prefer the newer syntax).

Comment: You are absolutely right on your guess Sir. Thank you, your answer cleared it up for me, I wasn't sure if these two queries would actually be interpreted the same.