# How do I correctly wrap a query in a SELECT * FROM (...) with MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a query that I need to split into two parts and connect with UNION. The two parts work independently; however when I use the "SELECT * FROM (...)" I get the error:

```
SQLException in getScoutTroopDetails: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'at_cub_details.cd_id' not found.
```

I have stripped the query right down to bare minimum that shows the error (i.e., removed the joins, union, etc).

This works:

```
String selectQry2 = (
            "(SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id, at_cub_details.cd_scout_no, at_cub_details.cd_surname, " +
              "at_cub_details.cd_first_name, at_cub_details.cd_dob, at_cub_details.cd_archived, " +
              "at_section_details.sd_start_date " +

              "FROM at_account_group, at_section_details, at_group, at_cub_details " +

              "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? " + 
                " AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                " AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id " +
                " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id " +
              "GROUP BY at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name, at_cub_details.cd_id)");
```

And this fails with the error above:

```
String selectQry2 = ("SELECT * FROM " +
            "(SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id, at_cub_details.cd_scout_no, at_cub_details.cd_surname, " +
              "at_cub_details.cd_first_name, at_cub_details.cd_dob, at_cub_details.cd_archived, " +
              "at_section_details.sd_start_date " +

              "FROM at_account_group, at_section_details, at_group, at_cub_details " +

              "WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? " + 
                " AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                " AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id " +
                " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id " +
              "GROUP BY at_cub_details.cd_surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name, at_cub_details.cd_id) AS a ");
```

Comment: You really should be using JOIN's instead of `FROM at_account_group, at_section_details, at_group, at_cub_details`

Comment: Hi Riggs, Why? Is this more efficient/faster or just easier to read? I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598416/oracle-db-joins-vs-from-a-b-c However, it does not state any benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, You need to reference your tables with alias (Your SQL is unnecessarily longer). Second try to use a join instead of all those tables. Third your java code is unable to reference the column because you are now querying from table `A`.

```
 CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `idperson` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idperson`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

select a.idperson from (select p.idperson from test.person as p) as a;
```

I hope that helps.